# How to Edit Google Docs title with Google Docs API?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I have tried Create, batchUpdate, get from https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview.

Even in `batchUpdate` I don't see option to edit `title`. I have used this to edit the contents of the document - insert/delete, but not title.

How can I edit a document title given that I have document id?
Is there any way to edit document title using API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to modify the title of Google Document.

  - Namely, you want to modify the filename of Google Document.

For this, how about this answer?

In order to modify the filename of Google Document, you can achieve this using the method of "Files: update" in Drive API. Unfortunately, Google Docs API cannot be used for modifying the filename of Google Document.

#### Endpoint:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

#### Sample request body:

```
{"name":"updated title"}
```

#### Sample curl:

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{documentId}' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"updated title"}' \
  --compressed
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: update in Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

### Added:

When you want to request using the browser, you can use [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) for authorization and [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) for modifying the title. As a sample script, I show you the sample script of the method of Files: update for Javascript as follows. Please use the authorization script from [the quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js).

#### Sample script:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.update({
  fileId: fileId,
  resource: {name: "updated title"},
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I see. Since the google docs are stored in Drive, Drive api can be used whenever possible! I will have to look for Browser/JS version for this.

Comment: @mythicalcoder Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script for Javascript. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, seems like that's what I needed.